# Odoo 8.0: Программное сохранение записи в форме по событию on_change

Tags: python, odoo

Необходимо по событию **on_change** на поле Name сохранить создаваемую запись в базу и **остаться в форме редактирования записи** (см. рис. ниже)

Форма в режиме создания записи
  [image: Форма создания записи до сохранения]

А вот такую форму необходимо получить после отработки события on_change:

[image: Форма после создания/сохранения записи в режиме редактирования]

Обратите внимание, что форма находится в режиме редактирования, но системное поле идентификатора id инициализирована и в таблице уже существует запись.

Код (который создает запись при изменении поля Name, но это не решает проблему, т.к. при нажатии на кнопку Create создается еще одна запись):

```
from openerp import models, fields, api

class Master(models.Model):
    _name = 'att.master'

    name = fields.Char("Name")
    qty = fields.Integer("Qty")

    @api.onchange('name')
    def _on_change_name(self):
        if self.name:
            self.qty += 100
            print 'The on_change event was happened'
            self.env['att.master'].create({'name': self.name, 'qty': self.qty} )
```

View:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <openerp>
    <data>
        <!-- form AGREEMENT -->
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="att_master_view_form">
            <field name="name">Master</field>
            <field name="model">att.master</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Master">
                    <sheet>
                        <group colspan="4">
                                <field name="name"/>
                                <field name="qty"/>
                                <field name="id"/>
                        </group>
                    </sheet>
            </form>
            </field>
        </record>

        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="att_master_view_tree">
            <field name="name">List of master</field>
            <field name="model">att.master</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree string="List of master">
                    <field name="name"/>
                    <field name="qty"/>
                    <field name="id"/>
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>

        <!-- window action -->
        <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="att_master_list_action">
            <field name="name">Master</field>
            <field name="res_model">att.master</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        </record>

        <menuitem id="att_master_menuitem" name="Master"
                  parent="att_menu_agreement"
                  action="att_master_list_action"/>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `new` вместо `create`:

```
self.new({'name': self.name, 'qty': self.qty})
```